# DiscordAPIError: Unknown Interaction - Discord.js V13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am getting this error when trying to collect interactions and I can not manage to fix it. I've tried using `deferUpdate()` and `deferReply()` but it seems like the interaction gets deleted as its colected because it keeps giving me the same error.

Thank you all in advance for your help!

Code:

```js
        let filter1 = (i) => i.user.id === message.author.id;

        const col = msg.createMessageComponentCollector({
            filter: filter1,
            componentType: "SELECT_MENU",
            time: 600000
        })

        col.on('collect', async i => {
            if (i.values[0] === 'etitle') {
                await i.reply({
                    content: `La opción **Titulo** fue seleccionada. Por favor, introduce un titulo para el embed.`,
                    ephemeral: true
                })
                let t1 = await message.channel.awaitMessages({
                    filter: filter2,
                    max: 1
                })

                let title = t1.first().content;
                pre.setTitle(title)
                result.setTitle(title)
                t1.first().delete().catch(err => null)
                preview.edit({
                    content: `**Vista previa:**`,
                    embeds: [pre]
                })
            }
}
```

Error:

```
5|  | DiscordAPIError: Unknown interaction
5|  |     at RequestHandler.execute (/home/bots/ICECLUB/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:298:13)
5|  |     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
5|  |     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
5|  |     at async RequestHandler.push (/home/bots/ICECLUB/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:50:14)
5|  |     at async SelectMenuInteraction.reply (/home/bots/ICECLUB/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/interfaces/InteractionResponses.js:99:5)
5|  |     at async InteractionCollector.<anonymous> (/home/bots/ICECLUB/commands/utilidad/embeder.js:152:17) {
5|  |   method: 'post',
5|  |   path: '/interactions/884259771329413141/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246ODg0MjU5NzcxMzI5NDEzMTQxOldic09VZFd3V3NZVjFuZmhndzZ5U2pxMGFjMWxoMmpaaG5GcU5Lczd4SzA5bDV4YjNvUjNLTFJUQzBRdG90clpuekdhOENGV1RkSXA4bXp3aFI4YXFtTGZzWEs2UlViSHJaOW83ODVwUE9FejBGSGVqbWR5eHlXSm1iYUc3TGtS/callback',
5|  |   code: 10062,
5|  |   httpStatus: 404,
5|  |   requestData: { json: { type: 4, data: [Object] }, files: [] }
5|  | }
```